# Error envio de dados xml

Tags: angularjs, ionic, typescript

Estou com seguinte mensagem:

```
[{erro: "Formato de usuário inválido"}]
```

Código typescript

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('user', 'meuLogin');
    urlSearchParams.append('pass', 'minhaSenha');
    urlSearchParams.append('cod', 'meuCodigo');
let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

return this.http
  .post('meuXml.asp', body, {headers:headers})
    .map(data => {
      console.log(data.json())
  }, error => {
      console.log(error.json());
  });
```

Comment: `Content-Type`  não deveria ser `application/xml` ou `text/xml` ?

Comment: Também coloquei dessa forma que você falou, porém erro ainda persisti

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa package https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js, o seu body no caso é uma urlString, que não está no formato de xml

Comment: Tenho que converter de XML to JSON ?

Comment: Quando você acessa a página `meuXml.asp` direto no navegador o que acontece ?

Comment: Acontece que ele me retorna o xml para enviar os dados correspondente a cada tag